# how to edit the pageSize of kendogrid to make 1-10 of 100 in this change color and clickable to execute a function

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a kendo grid which uses traditional [kendoGridBinding]="gridData" like this -

```
`<kendo-grid #grid [kendoGridBinding]="gridData"  [pageable]="true"  
 [pageSize]="5" style="cursor:pointer">

<kendo-grid-column *ngFor="let column of columns" [field]="getColumnField(column)" [title]="getColumnTitle(column)" [width]="getColumnWidth(column)">
</kendo-grid-column>

</kendo-grid>
`
```

It shows the pageSize like 1-5 of 10. I am looking for a way so i can make pageSize  clickable to execute a function and also change color of pageSize buttons.  is it possible to do it. if yes can someone put any light to show how can i approach towards it. thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You override the existing pager by nesting a `ng-template` with the directive `kendoPagerTemplate` inside your `kendo-grid`.

This way you can use custom elements and logic inside the pager. ([API-Reference](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-operations/paging/#toc-pager-template))

```
<kendo-grid>
    ...
    <ng-template kendoPagerTemplate>
        <!-- add custom components or reuse existing pager elements --->
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid>
```

Comment: i cannot use ng-grid since my application is in angular 2 r.c.1 so it supports only template instead of ng-template.